# Need Related List of Notes and Attachments only but fetching full Contact Details

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, standard-objects, standardcontroller

I would really appreciate if someone can help me over this.

Requirement - I need a Notes and attachment of particular contact on VF page.

I created a VF page in which I am calling related list of Notes and Attachment.

```
<apex:page title="Notes and Attachments" standardController="Contact">
    <apex:detail relatedList="false"/>
    <apex:relatedList list="CombinedAttachments" id="notes" subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"/>
</apex:page>
```

the URL of this page is 
https://myInstance.visual.force.com/apex/NotesAttachment?id=contact_id&sfdc.override=1

everything is working fine.
but when i open the page it has Contact fields below the page Notes and Attachment related list.

[image]

I just want the Notes and Attachment section only.
I am little new salesforce if anyone can help me, I would really appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: only thing you want is Notes & Attachments ?

Comment: yes only one thing Notes & Attachments section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<apex:detail>` from your code

Try this Code :

`<apex:page title="Notes and Attachments" standardController="Contact">
    <apex:relatedList list="CombinedAttachments" id="notes" subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"/>
</apex:page>`

Your UI look like as following Image :[image]

Comment: ok let me try..

Comment: Thanks @HSdev.. it works..
May I know the reason why because of `<apex:detail relatedList="false"/>` it was fetching all the contact fields??

Comment: welcome :) don't forget to mark this as solved !!